# What does the text on the UFO image in the X Files opening credits mean?

Tags: the-x-files

This is a close-up of the bottom right corner of the UFO image in the opening credits of the X Files, the first image after the show title card.
[image: X Files UFO image closeup]

The text says:

> FBI PHOTO INTERPRETATION
>
> COMPUTER ENHANCEMENT
>
> EX69357012/55328 WASH HQ

The first two lines are pretty clear, especially in the context of the show, but does anyone have any clues about the third line? All my googling has turned up squat so far, not even a lead to follow.

Comment: looks like an attempt to simulate a realistic looking document id. Ex probably means "Exhibit". WASH HQ should be obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple file, record, or exhibit number, indicating which file the photo belongs to, and where the file is located (FBI headquarters in Washington DC, i.e. Langley). Nothing special about it.

A quick check for copies of FBI background check responses and FOIA replies does not show this format of a record number being used. Then again. many FBI records for paranormal or extraterrestrial events from the 90s would still be classified and not responsive to FOIA requests, so umm, maybe it's a real exhibit number, we just don't have security clearance to see it.

Comment: Does it refer to an actual file, or was it just doctored up for the show? Any idea?

Comment: @kenbellows doubt it, but see my edit.